Facing Static Asset can not be loaded issue after upgrading webpack from 4.0 to 5.0
I am recently update our webpack version from 4.0 to 5.0. Here is the webpack and its loader versions I used in the packake.json file.
    "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.9",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"

Except ts-loader, we all set the dependencies to be the latest version, and we are using node 14 in this case.
And I keep the webpack.config almost no change except the function config.outputwhich get updated.
Here is the index file we used in our server package
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (nextConfig = {}) => {
  return Object.assign({}, nextConfig, {
    webpack(config, options) {
      const { isServer } = options;

      config.output.chunkLoadingGlobal = 'loginServiceJsonP'; // this function get updated
      config.output.hotUpdateGlobal = 'loginServiceWebpackJsonp'; // this function get updated

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|webp|woff2)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
          options: {
            limit: false,
            fallback: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            publicPath: '/',
            /**
             * The `require` call we see here, is resolved exclusively
             * by webpack.
             * @param p the original image path.
             * @return {string} Returns the image url with the CDN prefixed.
             */
            postTransformPublicPath: (p) => `require('@amzn/ring-site-assets-resolver/src/setup-webpack-assets.js').assetsEndpoint + ${p}`,
            outputPath: `${isServer ? '../' : ''}../dist/assets/login`, // put assets in /dist/assets/login
            name: '[path][name]-[contenthash].[ext]', // use contenthash to generate hash based on content and NOT build
            context: 'static/' // use to strip /static/ from output
          },
        }],
      });

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.static-js$/,
        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
        options: {
          limit: false,
          fallback: require.resolve('file-loader'),
          publicPath: '/',
          /**
           * The `require` call we see here, is resolved exclusively
           * by webpack.
           * @param p the original image path.
           * @return {string} Returns the image url with the CDN prefixed.
           */
          postTransformPublicPath: (p) => `require('@amzn/ring-site-assets-resolver/src/setup-webpack-assets.js').assetsEndpoint + ${p}`,
          outputPath: '../dist/assets/login', // put assets in /dist/assets/login
          name: '[path][name]-[contenthash].js', // use contenthash to generate hash based on content and NOT build
          context: 'static/' // use to strip /static/ from output
        },
      });

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: false,
              fallback: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              publicPath: '/',
              /**
               * The `require` call we see here, is resolved exclusively
               * by webpack.
               * @param p the original image path.
               * @return {string} Returns the image url with the CDN prefixed.
               */
              postTransformPublicPath: (p) => `require('@amzn/ring-site-assets-resolver/src/setup-webpack-assets.js').assetsEndpoint + ${p}`,
              outputPath: '../dist/assets/login', // put assets in /dist/assets/login
              name: '[path][name]-[contenthash].css', // use contenthash to generate hash based on content and NOT build
              context: 'static/' // use to strip /static/ from output
            },
          },
          {
            // To inline url("../icons/arrow-down.svg") in common-styles.css.
            loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                config: false,
                plugins: [
                  require('postcss-url')({ url: 'inline' })
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      });

      if (typeof nextConfig.webpack === 'function') {
        return nextConfig.webpack(config, options);
      }

      return config;
    }
  });
}

I have verified that the output path is correct, we are deploying to code to aws code-pipeline running on ecr docker. Docker image share the same path as our local machine.
Our local asset file path is <servicePackage>/dist/assets/login and the webpack index file is located under
<servicePackage>/webpack/withAssets

When I get server code deployed to ecr, the static assets failed to render with error as below
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Refused to execute script from '<service endpoint url>/404' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

VM733:73 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initRingSiteHeapJS')
    at <anonymous>:73:22
    at consent-manager.js?l…&loggedIn=0:1:23208
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at consent-manager.js?l…&loggedIn=0:1:23118
    at e.value (consent-manager.js?l…&loggedIn=0:1:23292)
    at e.value (consent-manager.js?l…&loggedIn=0:1:11932)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (consent-manager.js?l…&loggedIn=0:1:26709)

Wondering am I missing any setup in the config or index file?
Appreciate for any hints and helps!!
Can someone help to answer why the upgrade of webpack 5 will introduce this issue, is dependencies issue or config issue?

for the first two errors of MIME type it's because the CSS styles are sent as HTML file you can fix it by importing CSS files into your main JS file and deleting all CSS link tags from HTML webpack will take care of it.
An example from my own project:
import "./styles/style.css";
import "./styles/utils.css";
import "./styles/var.css";

Webpack config file for loaders:
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },

You can omit the Bable and Img loader the first style loaders fix your issue.

Appreciate a lot, will try it out for this change will let you know how's the out come.

I commented out the url-loader for "/.css$/i" files in our case, and I added styler-loader and css-loader for loaders in the rule, but I still faced the similar error when running server. Might be some other config misse. Keeping looking into the issue thanks for the hints anyway.

For some reason, it turns out we need to migrate to asset module in our case. We also need the webpack_public_path to determine the public path which we need to calculate on fly aka running time.
